# Getting proporties of element in ng-repeat returns undefined in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get height of the current element in ng-repeat.

When I'm logging `element` I can see in console the whole object with the `clientHeight` property. But if I'm logging `element[0].clientHeight` separately console returns `undefined`..

What I'm doing wrong?

**JS**

```
app.directive('photo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log( element[0].clientHeight);
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="media in mediaScope" class="gallery_media col-xs-6">
    <img photo ng-src="{{ media.url }}">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it `undefined` or `0`? Should be `0` because the `img` hasn't yet loaded

Comment: @alliswell take a look at mine answer, would help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `onload` event on that element, That will get call when img fro `src` attribute is loaded

**Directive**

```
app.directive('photo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('load', function(){
                console.log( element[0].clientHeight);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The pankajparkar response is right, but restriction parameter should be set to 'A'.

```
restrict: 'A'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andresrondan/kaL5eot0/1/

Comment: by defaults `restrict: 'A'` only..why you want to specify it..bdw you had same code..which I have posted..